# Howto filter for UUID or name in web-bluetooth

Tags: javascript, web-bluetooth

I would like to handle a few toy controllers with one javascript setup. Some of them advertise a UUID and some only their name. So I would like to filter for a set of specific UUIDs or names. However, the following code will only find the devices advertising UUIDs but not the ones using their names.

This is the filter I am trying to use to filter for a set of four different devices. Two advertising a UUID and two only advertising their name:

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice( {
filters: [
    { services: ['0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb' ] },
    { services: ['7b130100-ce8d-45bb-9158-631b769139e9'] },
    { name: 'BT Control Receiver'},
    { name: 'BT Smart Controller'}
] } );
```

On the other hand filtering by the names only does indeed make either of those two devices show up in the selector:

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice( {
filters: [
    { name: 'BT Control Receiver'},
    { name: 'BT Smart Controller'}
] } );
```

But of course then the UUID based devices won't show up.

I cannot entirely switch to names as the UUID based devices can be renamed.

How do I request devices by UUID or name in the same request?

See https://github.com/harbaum/ftduino/blob/master/www/ec/code.js#L516 for the full code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is correct. The list of filters is supposed to be ORed together. We've had a bug like this before in Chromium when mixing name and UUID filters. Please open an issue by visiting https://crbug.com/new and including details about which platforms you've tested on.

Comment: Indeed, I just verified that this is platform dependent and only happens under chromium on linux. The filter works as expected on Android using chrome. I'll open a bug for that with more details. Thanks for the reply!